# Installing ruby-2.1.2: Cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, rvm

Getting few errors while installing ruby-2.1.2 using rvm. I am new to ruby and hence need assistance. Please let me know

Installation log and other relevant information here: [log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RTXNP2D25K/)

From the log provided in problem description, I have ruby 2.1.2 installed in the system. However, getting error when tried listing gems with `gem list` due to installation errors.After changing to 2.1.2 i.e., `rvm use 2.1.2` and executing `ruby -r openssl -e 'puts OpensSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'` gives this error:

> /Users/praveenk.k/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError) from /Users/praveenk.k/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require'

Comment: OpenSSL is proably not on your machine. Check if it is there with `which openssl`.

Comment: `which openssl` prints the output `/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/openssl` . Hence I assume I have openssl present in my system.

Comment: OK, your issue seems to not be an openssl issue. What you can try next: look at file /Users/praveenk.k/.rvm/log/1576471018_ruby-2.1.2/gem.install.gem-wrappers->=1.4.0.log. Share the Content of this file with us.

Comment: contents of `cat "/Users/praveenk.k/.rvm/log/1576471018_ruby-2.1.2/gem.install.gem-wrappers->=1.4.0.log"` is like this: `ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
 cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Please put the text of your last comment in your original post. This way it is easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ruby <2.4 is incompatible with OpenSSL 1.1 (e.g see https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1353).

Just a hunch, but if you're using Mac + Homebrew, OpenSSL 1.0 was recently deleted, so anything along the lines of `brew upgrade openssl` would trash that.

There are several options to deal with this:

1. I have older Rubies via `asdf` installed with LibreSSL (which may be safer anyway, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112545/what-are-the-main-advantages-of-using-libressl-in-favor-of-openssl):

```
$ openssl
OpenSSL> version
LibreSSL 2.8.3
```

2. Compile and link your own OpenSSL 1.0 (or then set compiler flags as environment variables when building Ruby -- https://rvm.io/rubies/installing)
3. See if your system's package manager allows you to access openssl 1.0 and install with that (was helping a coworker with this recently and we weren't able to find a good keg for homebrew at this time, unfortunately)

There might be something less convoluted than that; if someone has ideas, please feel free to comment or give an alternate answer.

**EDIT**

I personally ran into this issue with some other software and discovered that this fixed it, since the old SSL version was sitting around still:

```
brew switch openssl 1.0.2s
```

Should work so long as Homebrew doesn't "helpfully" clean that out for me.

Comment: that really helped! I followed this [link](https://mentalized.net/journal/2019/09/13/ruby-2-3-rvm-and-openssl-1-0/)

Comment: "brew switch openssl 1.0.2s" gives "Error: Unknown command: switch"

Answer (score 28):

Worked example

```
brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0
rvm install 2.1.2 -C --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl@1.0`
```

It's from https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4819#issuecomment-595644550

Answer (score 12):

For debian 10 :

sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev

Answer (score 6):

On mac BigSur, I fixed it via

```
$ rvm pkg install openssl
$ rvm install 2.1.2 -C --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

or you can also try with

```
$ rvm pkg install openssl
$ CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rvm install 2.1.2 -C --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Comment: First approach worked on Mojave. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For me solve this in centos 7

```
$ openssl version -a


OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(8x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: gcc -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DKRB5_MIT -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -Wa,--noexecstack -DPURIFY -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DRC4_ASM -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM

------------------------------------------------------------------------
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls" <- ************* COPY THIS PATH *************
------------------------------------------------------------------------

engines:  rdrand dynamic
```

paste the path in the bellow line how --with-openssl-dir param

```
$ RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=/etc/pki/tls" rbenv install 2.7.2
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X Big Sur, to install Ruby 2.3.2 with RVM, the fix was

```
brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0
CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rvm reinstall ruby-2.2.5 --with-openssl-dir='/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0'
```

Reference was here -- https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4889

Answer (score 0):

On Amazon Linux 2, even if openssl is installed, you need the full dev kit

```
yum install openssl-devel
```