# Unable to install any ruby version using rvm in Mac catalina 10.15.2

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, rvm

Error running '__rvm_package_extract /Users/name/.rvm/archives/ruby-2.3.2.tar.bz2 /Users/name/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_10476',
please read /Users/name/.rvm/log/1579150426_ruby-2.3.2/extract.log
There has been an error while trying to extract the source. Halting the installation.
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.

`Log file:`
[2020-01-16 10:23:46] __rvm_package_extract

````
    rvm_debug __rvm_package_extract:$#: "$@"
    \typeset __extract_src __extract_target __tempdir __path __file __return
    __extract_src="$1" 
    __extract_target="$2" 
    shift 2
    __return=0 
    __tempdir="$( TMPDIR="${rvm_tmp_path}" mktemp -d -t rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX )" 
    __rvm_package_extract_run "$__extract_src" "$__tempdir" "$@" || __return=$? 
    if (( __return == 0 ))
    then
        for __path in "$__tempdir"/*
        do
            __file="${__path##*/}" 
            if [[ -n "${__file}" && -e "$__extract_target/${__file}" ]]
            then
                \command \rm -rf "$__extract_target/${__file}" || __return=$? 
            fi
            \command \mv -f "${__path}" "$__extract_target/" || __return=$? 
        done
    fi
    if [[ -n "$__tempdir" ]]
    then
        \command \rm -rf "$__tempdir"
    fi
    return $__return
}```
current path: /Users/name/.rvm/src
PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin:/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/ name/.rvm/bin
GEM_HOME=
GEM_PATH=
command(3): __rvm_package_extract /Users/name/.rvm/archives/ruby-2.3.2.tar.bz2 /Users/name/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_10476
````

Comment: Maybe you want to report the exact steps you followed for the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your `PATH`, it looks like you're trying to build Ruby 2.3.x with OpenSSL 1.1, which is not compatible with Rubies < 2.4.x. I suspect that RVM would be happy to build the latest Ruby version, though you should confirm this given the title says "any" Ruby version. If there's an issue with that, then check the logs and see if the failure is similar or for a different reason.

I'd suggest getting the latest Ruby to build as a way to rule out other factors, then deal with the SSL version problem for your 2.3 install.

See [Installing ruby-2.1.2: Cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59350892/installing-ruby-2-1-2-cannot-load-such-file-openssl-loaderror) among other recent questions about Ruby and OpenSSL 1.1

Comment: Actually you are correct, any 2.3.x  version is failing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps you can try to resolve this issue:

Stpe-1: Uninstall RVM and all its components:

```
rvm implode
```

Stpe-2: Clean up your system of any RVM-related files:

```
rm -rf ~/.rvm
```

Stpe-3: Reinstall RVM:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Stpe-4: Load RVM into your shell session:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Stpe-5: Install the desired version of Ruby using RVM:

```
rvm install ruby-version
```