# After installing ruby-2.3.3 unable to install gems - openssl

Tags: ruby, openssl, rubygems, rvm

I am able to run install `rvm install ruby-2.3.3` which seems to be installing successfully with some issues:

```
ruby-2.3.3 - #downloading ruby-2.3.3, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.3.3 - #extracting ruby-2.3.3 to /Users/jonathonday/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.3.....
ruby-2.3.3 - #applying patch /Users/jonathonday/.rvm/patches/ruby/ruby_2_3_gcc7.patch.
ruby-2.3.3 - #applying patch /Users/jonathonday/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.3.3/random_c_using_NR_prefix.patch.
ruby-2.3.3 - #configuring...........................................................
ruby-2.3.3 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.3.3 - #compiling...........................................................
ruby-2.3.3 - #installing.........
ruby-2.3.3 - #making binaries executable..
ruby-2.3.3 - #downloading rubygems-3.0.6
ruby-2.3.3 - #extracting rubygems-3.0.6......
ruby-2.3.3 - #removing old rubygems........
ruby-2.3.3 - #installing rubygems-3.0.6...............................................
ruby-2.3.3 - #gemset created /Users/jonathonday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global
ruby-2.3.3 - #importing gemset /Users/jonathonday/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems..................there was an error installing gem gem-wrappers
.................there was an error installing gem rubygems-bundler
.........................there was an error installing gem rvm
.......
ruby-2.3.3 - #generating global wrappers.................
Error running 'run_gem_wrappers regenerate',
please read /Users/jonathonday/.rvm/log/1581851603_ruby-2.3.3/gemset.wrappers.global.log
ruby-2.3.3 - #gemset created /Users/jonathonday/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3
ruby-2.3.3 - #importing gemsetfile /Users/jonathonday/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-2.3.3 - #generating default wrappers.................
Error running 'run_gem_wrappers regenerate',
please read /Users/jonathonday/.rvm/log/1581851603_ruby-2.3.3/gemset.wrappers.default.log
ruby-2.3.3 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
Install of ruby-2.3.3 - #complete
```

However, When I try to install gems or see which gems are listed I get the following error:

```
jonathonday@Jonathons-MacBook-Air:~$ gem list
ERROR:  Loading command: list (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I am unsure how to resolve this as there seem to be a number of different issues.

For clarity I am using a macbook air (MacOS - version 10.14.5) and homebrew.

If anyone could help with this I would be very grateful - I am just looking to be able to install gems and use this version as normal.

--EDIT--

Following the comments below I followed the instructions on [this link](https://mentalized.net/journal/2019/09/13/ruby-2-3-rvm-and-openssl-1-0/) and was able to resolve the issue. Thank you again to everyone who commented and tried to help.

Comment: Ruby 2.3 reached end-of-life almost a year ago and 2.3.3 is not even the latest version of 2.3. Is it an option to update?

Comment: Possibly - I am completing a university course and that is the version they have on the school VDI and suggest we use to avoid compatibility issues. 

I actually have built the assignment using Ruby 2.6, will there be any issues as far as you know if they tried to run it on their systems?

The app is based on Sinatra and uses active record and sqlite3 gems mainly (very basic wiki). Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: Seems like variations of this question have come up a lot lately. The issue is that Rubies older than version 2.4 use OpenSSL1.0, which has been deprecated on Macs in favor of 1.1. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59350892/installing-ruby-2-1-2-cannot-load-such-file-openssl-loaderror

Comment: Cheers! answers were certainly helpful and I will give them a go!