# Ruby 2.2.3 in 2020

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.2

Ruby 2.2.3 has been dead for a while and yet I've been asked to look at a legacy project in order to update and fix it.
I can't get 2.2.3 to install in order to get a local env up and running on either MacOS or Ubuntu.

The error seems to be down to an openssl rubygems issue:

from `rubygems.install.log`

```
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:1222 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:1231 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
/Users/user/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.8/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how proceed?

Comment: Ruby 2.x is almost entirely backward-compatible. If it works on 2.2.3, chances are good it will also work on 2.6 or 2.7. If you haven't yet, I'd advise trying to set it up on a current Ruby and seeing what happens. But if you really want 2.2.3, your question is likely a dupe of [Installing ruby-2.1.2: Cannot load such file — openssl (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59350892/installing-ruby-2-1-2-cannot-load-such-file-openssl-loaderror).

Comment: @Amadan There's some friction above 2.3.3 with things like the obsolete `mysql` gem, but on modern codebases that use modern dependencies I have to agree that there's not many issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MacOS using rbenv instead of rvm solves this issue and has allowed me to move onto another host of dependency issues.

Comment: Congratulations on shaving part of the yak!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ brew update && brew upgrade 
$ brew doctor
```

Solve all brew doctor warnings, then proceed further

```
$ brew uninstall ruby
$ brew install rbenv 
$ brew install ruby-build 
$ echo 'export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ rbenv install -l
$ rbenv install 2.2.3
$ rbenv global 2.2.3
```